# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity

I have a `BaseController` that has a property called `UserGuid` to facilitate access to user data:

```
private UserManager<User> UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
    }
}

public Guid UserGuid
{
    get
    {
        var userGuid = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result.Guid;
        return userGuid;
    }
}
```

However, sometimes I get this error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

And it's related to this line:

```
var userGuid = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result.Guid;
```

The point is, `UserManager` is not my code.

What should I do to fix this bug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are already question about this... Where the answer is to modify connection string to allow multiple recordsets... (obviously UserManager is badly written and reusing connection, while there is already connection pool internally based on connection string) Also using async method synchronously is terrible idea...

Answer (score -1):

If you sometimes have the problem (and not always) maybe is because you are not awaiting the UserManager.FindByNameAsync function

Try with this:

```
var userGuid = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name).Result.Guid;
```

If you called multiple times that function and you are not awaiting it's possible to have that error

Comment: Irrelevant... Also if you wana use await(yes, that's how it should be done) then there would be no Result... As this is Task property.... More over this cannot be done in getter

Comment: Why there wouldn't be result?

Comment: Because when you use await the return value would not be Task anymore...